# Get Posts that are in the current month or later

Tags: posts, wp-query, query

I have a custom post type that is an Event.

I'm trying to query those Events and only return Events that are in the current month or later. So the event could be in the past, but it has to be in the same month. The event date is a custom field.

So right now I would only want events that were in the month of August or later, and no events prior to August.

Here's my current query, ordered from oldest to newest:

```
$custom_post_type = 'event';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date_and_time',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$events = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: how did you saved time value inside `event_date_and_time`. Is it unix timestamp? string? Please provide details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `meta_query`, if you date information is saved in custom field. Like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date_and_time',
            'value' => current_time('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

This code suppose you date is saved in YYYYMMDD format (20150820). And it shows post from today to future, so you will have to change `value` to "first day of current month".

Answer (score 0):

Use `meta_query` argument in the array.

```
$custom_post_type = 'event';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date_and_time',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date_and_time',
            'value'   => date("Y-m-1"); // starting from 1st of current month. This will change based on how you store dates.
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC,' // Let WordPress know we're working with numbers
        )
    )
);

$events = get_posts($args);
```